# How to stop scrolling of AChartEngine dynamic line graph along the y-axis?

Tags: android, graph, charts, plot, achartengine

I have set min max range for y-axis values but graph can scroll beyond those values which hampers the look and feel of graph. I wish to control/stop scrolling of graph along the y-axis. How can I do that?

Comment: how did you set these ranges?

Comment: by using mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
  mRenderer.setXAxisMax(10);
  mRenderer.setYAxisMin(20);
  mRenderer.setYAxisMax(200);

Comment: and the graph still automatically re-sizes along the y-axis even though these values are in place?

Comment: yes. because this range only specifies the visible range. But if we scroll it along y-axis downward/upward, graph scrolls and I want to stop that scrolling.

Comment: So, the command works as it's supposed to but you don't want it to *pan* along the y-axis, when scrolled *by the user*, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is specify which axis panning is available for: `mRenderer.setPanEnabled(boolean enabledX, boolean enabledY)`

[Click here for more](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html#setPanEnabled%28boolean,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 6):

use the following for locking both x and y axis scrolling, based on our need boolean values can be specified

```
render.setPanEnabled(false, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

use setPanLimits method.

mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{0,10,0,5});

this code will disable panning beyond 0 to the left,10 to the right on X axis,and beyond 0 down and 5 up on Y axis.